# Probability of two variables doing the same thing a certain percentage of times, when we know how often they each do something individually

Tags: probability

**EDIT: I've edited this question to include the probability stage of calculations. Thanks to Henry for getting me started.**

I'm exploring some simple time series correlation data. And I want to show that two variables are not entirely uncorrelated from each other.

- Stock A went up 1052 out of 1984 weeks (53.02% of the weeks)
- Stock B went up 1069 out of 1984 weeks (53.88% of the weeks)
- There are no weeks where either stock remains level, they always rise or fall
- The individual data points are all available, if this helps determine a best method.

My question is: *What is the probability that both stocks will move in the same direction (up or down) on at least 60.13% of the weeks (≈1193 weeks of the 1984)?*

The probabilities of each event (if I have calculated correctly) are:

- Probability of both up (0.5302 x 0.5388) = 0.2857
- Probability of A up and B down (0.5302 x 0.4612) = 0.2445
- Probability of both down (0.4698 x 0.4612) = 0.2167
- Probability of B up and A down (0.4698 x 0.5388) = 0.2531
- Total = 1 ✓

So, the probability they both go in the same direction (0.2857 + 0.2167) = 0.5024

I have looked at binomial calculations and normal approximations, and I understand that I can use these to find the likelihood of a single data point being a certain distance from the mean. But I can't figure out how I would use these to calculate *The probability that both stocks will move in the same direction (up or down) on at least 60.13% of the weeks*

**2nd Edit:** I've run a weighted random simulator in Excel with the probabilities calculated above and this shows there is almost no change of that 60.13% being random. But I would still like a tiny number to further support this.

[image: Weighted random simulation]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can work out the probability assuming independence of the two moving in the same direction and then use a binomial calculation or normal approximation for that exceeding a threshold (I would guess very small in your example).  What have you tried?

Comment: But independence is not what people would expect: there are times when most stocks move in the same direction, for example when interest changes happen or are predicted  to happen, so it would be natural to expect some correlation.

Comment: So basically I want to show exactly that. That two financial assets are likely to have some correlation, even if that's just them both being part of financial markets often trending together. I think I want to assume independence for the calculation and then say, _"it is very unlikely there is independence/no correlation here, as the probability both stocks would move in the same direction at least 60.13% of the weeks is x%"_.  I haven't tried anything except search for a way to calculate this (and fail), as I wasn't sure where to start. How do I calculate probability assuming independence?

Comment: Start with: What is the probability they both go up in a particular week (assuming independence)?  What is the probability they both go down?   What is the probability they move in the same direction in a particular week?